# creating multiple datatables in for each loop

Tags: vb.net, foreach, datatable

I have the following sub. I have an string array with e.g. 3 strings (a,b,c). I wanna fill datatables with data from excelsheets and name the tables a,b,c.

```
Sub create_Dataset(ByVal ParamArray DataTableNames() As String)
For Each FileElement In DataTableNames
...
MyConnection.Open()
da.Fill(DS, FileElement)
MyConnection.Close()
Dim dt As DataTable = DS.Tables(FileElement)
Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
Form1.DataGridView2.DataSource = DS.Tables(1)
```

Running this code give me an error "ds.Tables(1) doesnt exist. According to my understanding this is because i create only one table (Dim dt As DataTable = DS.Tables(FileElement))and put the data into this table over and over again. But how can i create a table for each array element?

Comment: Dim DS As New DataSet()

Comment: OK. I guess that you have got your response already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly add new DataTable to DataSet's Tables collection:

```
Sub create_Dataset(ByVal ParamArray DataTableNames() As String)
   Dim DT as DataTable
   MyConnection.Open()

   For Each FileElement In DataTableNames
   ...
       DT = New DataTable(FileElement)
       da.Fill(DT)
       DS.Tables.Add(DT)
   Next

   MyConnection.Close()

   Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
   Form1.DataGridView2.DataSource = DS.Tables(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have DS.Tables(1) ...

```
Sub create_Dataset(ByVal ParamArray DataTableNames() As String)
    Dim DS As New DataSet 

    MyConnection.Open()
    For Each FileElement In DataTableNames
        ...

        da.Fill(DS, FileElement)
    Next
    MyConnection.Close()

    Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
    Form1.DataGridView2.DataSource = DS.Tables(1)
End Sub
```